# setState synchronously with reactn?

Tags: javascript, react-native, reactn

I'm having trouble with setState when using the package: [`reactn`](https://github.com/CharlesStover/reactn)

---

When I replace [these lines (1)](https://github.com/loia5tqd001/DevC-React-Native-Weekly-Assignments/blob/cba47637bc3c72d27edbd06ecea4f8f5e3acdac4/Lab3/App.js#L25-L36) with [those lines (2)](https://github.com/loia5tqd001/DevC-React-Native-Weekly-Assignments/blob/cba47637bc3c72d27edbd06ecea4f8f5e3acdac4/Lab3/App.js#L38-L47), the code works. The (2) is a workaround, deals with asynchronous setState, but I want to understand **why (1) doesn't work**.

As I know, I can pass a callback function to `setSomeState` in [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates):

> If the new state is computed using the previous state, you can *pass a function* to `setState`

[This](https://github.com/CharlesStover/reactn#useglobal-1) is also another usage of `useGlobal` from the document of [`reactn`](https://github.com/CharlesStover/reactn#useglobal-1), which also uses a callback function as an argument for `setGlobal`. Why their example works but mine doesn't?

**Full code:** https://snack.expo.io/@loia5tqd001/d26e8f
**Snippets:**

```js
listSymbols = [ "USD", "EUR", ... ]
usdRates = {} // expect to be usdRates = { USD: 1, EUR: 0.9 ... }
// getExchangeRate is in utils/utils.js

// => The code doesn't work
    for (const symbol of listSymbols) {
      getExchangeRate("USD", symbol).then(exchangeRate => {

        setUsdRates(oldUsdRates => ({
          ...oldUsdRates, 
          [symbol]: exchangeRate 
        }))
        .then(() => console.log("Call api getting exchange rate for " + symbol, usdRates) )
      })
    }

// => The code works as expected
    for (const symbol of listSymbols) {
      getExchangeRate("USD", symbol).then(exchangeRate => {
        usdRates[symbol] = exchangeRate
        console.log("Call api got exchange rate for " + symbol, usdRates)
      })
    }

    setUsdRates(usdRates)
```

Comment: Please try to reduce your question to something that lets you put the code in question _in your question_, ideally in [mcve] form, because links to github repos are in no way guaranteed, and all you've done is hidden the information on what you're talking about off-site, so it isn't clear from your question what "this situation" is supposed to refer to. Please read through [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the source of reactn it doesn't appear that the updater function style is supported when using the `useGlobal('propertyName')` version of the hook.

Here is the definition of the property setter: https://github.com/CharlesStover/reactn/blob/master/src/use-global.ts#L95
You can see it creates a `newGlobalState` object and passes it to `setGlobal`.

Then `setGlobal` calls the `set` on the global state manager here: https://github.com/CharlesStover/reactn/blob/master/src/global-state-manager.ts#L302

Since `newGlobalState` from the property setter is always an object, the updater version is never used.

You could achieve what you want by passing nothing to `useGlobal` and dealing with the entire state object instead, as per the example in the docs that you linked:

```
const [global, setGlobal] = useGlobal();
...
      getExchangeRate("USD", symbol).then(exchangeRate => {

        setGlobal(oldGlobal => ({
          ...oldGlobal,
          usdRates: {
            ...oldGlobal.usdRates, 
            [symbol]: exchangeRate,
          }, 
        }))
        .then(() => console.log("Call api getting exchange rate for " + symbol, usdRates) )
      })
    }
```

Also I'm not sure your other example is 100% correct - you're not waiting to call `setUsdRates` until all of the async `getExchangeRate` calls are complete.

Comment: Clear, thank you. I tried and your solution works.
Btw thank you for pointing out the flaw in my other "works" example. What should I do to make sure `usdRates` is updated when calling `setUsdRates` in that "works" example though?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure the best way to do that if you want to use the `setUsdRates` - if you don't mind waiting for all of the exchange rates to be fetched before updating you could find a way to wrap all of the `getExchangeRate` calls in a `Promise.all`, and then call `setUsdRates` only once when the `Promise.all` resolves.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, it sounds reasonable. But I don't know why even if I delete the line `setUsdRates(usdRates)`, only set the variable directly `usdRates[symbol] = exchangeRate` the app still works as expected. I'm not capable yet to diagnose through the `reactn` library itself to see how it works. Could you help me point something out?

The `usdRates` global state is used in `utils/utils.js` only, and is initialized in `App.js`

Comment: If you're never calling the setter then you're not triggering the components that depend on `usdRates` to re-render, but the app will still work "correctly" if rendering is being forced by some other means like other state changes. You can verify this by getting rid of `useGlobal` altogether and using a simple object in `utils/utils`. The issue is that you won't be guaranteed to have the app re-render when the rates change, you will need to wait until rendering is triggered in some other way.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I will try to clear some things here
as you said

```
usdRates = {} // expect to be usdRates = { USD: 1, EUR: 0.9 ... }
```

So it's supposed to be an object

```
const [usdRates, setUsdRates] = useGlobal({})
```

then do

```
useEffect(() => {
for (const symbol of listSymbols) {
  getExchangeRate("USD", symbol).then(exchangeRate => {

    setUsdRates(oldUsdRates => ({
      ...oldUsdRates, 
      [symbol]: exchangeRate 
    }))
    .then(() => console.log("Call api getting exchange rate for " + symbol, usdRates) 
   )
  })
}
}, [])
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't describe the question clearly (and it's more frustrated to describe it than figure out myself in this special case) so I'll delete it in 5 minutes. Thank you for your help anyway.

Comment: I can understand , no problem